# Can you randomize a SMS response on Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Is there a way to randomize responses on your Twilio number? For example I send a text to the local number I purchased and Twilio looks at a list of responses and sends a text back from this list randomly?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this yourself, on your server.

Create an `end-point`, a page that returns TwiML (the Twilio markup language), host it on your server and expose it to Internet.

Configure your Twilio number, webhook option, with the URL of your end-point.

Here is some sample code you can put on your server to get you started:

```
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";


$input = array("Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
$rand_key = array_rand($input);


?>

<Response>
    <Message><?php echo $input[$rand_key] . "\n"; ?></Message>
</Response>
```

More here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey